# Contacts not being displayed in contact list but appears when trying to save a contact

Tags: contacts, backup, external-sd, lenovo-a6000-plus

I have Lenovo A6000+ smartphone. About 100 contacts have been removed when trying to backup contacts on SD card. But when I enter the phone no. of the removed contact, it reappears again in the contact list.

**what is the reason for this and how may this be resolved?**

Comment: @parthu_panther Editing is OK. But where is the solution...

Comment: You can try out with any contacts app available in play store. Does the problem continue with it?

Answer (score 0):

See if anything has changed in contact display settings. 
go to settings>contacts>contacts to display>and select "all"
Now it should show all your contacts.

Comment: "ALL" is selected already

Comment: When you find a contact and press on it, where is it saved to? In [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksdAs.jpg) you'll see that the contact is saved to Google contacts and WhatsApp. Which icons do you see in place of the one in the screenshot? See where it says connected via?

Comment: Also, do new contacts show up fine? And what happens when you edit this hidden contact, does it show up after that?